# sql inner join isnt workin like exPeCting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, left-join, inner-join

Im trying to get a simple JOIN Query with mysql to work.
I have two tables (see below).

My expected output are two Rows like you can see below.
But on my localhost the output are 265 rows? i dont even have that much inputs so they all duplicates.

How can i get this to work?

See below what i have so far.

Thanks

**Product Table (DB: products)**

```
| id | created_time | user_hash  | product_hash | title           |
|----| ------------ | ---------- | ------------ |---------------- |
| 0  | 2021-01-01   | 6dfb81562c | 5877a110     | Product Title 0 | x
| 1  | 2021-01-01   | ca69a68665 | 5877a111     | Product Title 1 |
| 2  | 2021-01-01   | 6dfb81562c | 5877a112     | Product Title 2 | x
| 3  | 2021-01-01   | ca69a68665 | 5877a113     | Product Title 3 |
| 4  | 2021-01-01   | ca69a68665 | 5877a113     | Product Title 4 |
| 5  | 2021-01-01   | ca69a68665 | 5877a113     | Product Title 5 |
| 6  | 2021-01-01   | 0d9a7e91fc | 5877a113     | Product Title 6 |
```

**Favourite Products Table (DB: favourites)**

```
| id | created_time | user_hash  | product_hash |
|----|--------------|------------|--------------|
| 0  | 2021-01-01   | 6dfb81562c | 5877a114     | x
| 1  | 2021-01-01   | 6dfb81562c | 5877a115     | x
| 2  | 2021-01-01   | 0d9a7e91fc | 5877a116     |
| 3  | 2021-01-01   | 0d9a7e91fc | 5877a117     | 
| 4  | 2021-01-01   | a5dc8c1d74 | 5877a118     |
```

**ExPeCted Output:**

```
| id | created_time | user_hash  | product_hash | title           |
|----| ------------ | ---------- | ------------ |---------------- |
| 0  | 2021-01-01   | 6dfb81562c | 5877a110     | Product Title 0 | x
| 1  | 2021-01-01   | 6dfb81562c | 5877a112     | Product Title 2 | x
```

**Actual Output:**

```
| id   | created_time | user_hash   | product_hash | title |
|------| ------------ | ----------- | ------------ |-------|
| 0    | 2021-01-01   | 8978b81562c | 5877a110     | ...   | 
| 1    | 2021-01-01   | 8978891562c | 5877a112     | ...   |
| 1    | 2021-01-01   | 6dfb81562c  | 5877a115     | ...   |
| 2    | 2021-01-01   | 0d9a7e91fc  | 5877a116     | ...   |
| 3    | 2021-01-01   | 0d9a7e91fc  | 5877a117     | ...   |
| 4    | 2021-01-01   | a5dc8c1d74  | 5877a118     | ...   |
| 5    | 2021-01-01   | 8978891562c | 5877a112     | ...   |
| 6    | 2021-01-01   | 6dfb81562c  | 5877a115     | ...   |
| 7    | 2021-01-01   | 0d9a7e91fc  | 5877a116     | ...   |
| ...  | 2021-01-01   | 0d9a7e91fc  | 5877a117     | ...   |
| 265  | 2021-01-01   | a5dc8c1d74  | 5877a118     | ...   |
```

**My Query:**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN favourites ON products.user_hash = favourites.user_hash "); 

$stmt->execute();
$i = 1;

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo '#'.$i. ' Row'; 
$i++
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the command directly in mysql workbench ?

Comment: i ran it in the phpmyadmin sql operation filed... same output

Comment: Why would your expect *this* output from *that* query!?! Anyway, this question has been asked often enough